# FME Server Workspace

Tags: fme-form

I published a workspace on FME Server. The workspace converts Geodatabase Files to MapInfo TAB.  I'd like to call the **generic workspace** with FME Server to convert other geodatabase.

Any idea?

Comment: Going to need more information, like what your server log for the job says. So we can see what may be happening.

Comment: OK. I have many File Geodatabase to converted into several files -> MapInfo, Excel, KML.  I don't know how I make my workbench to make it generic. I like to call it on the server FME whenever I need to convert a geodatabase to MapInfo or KML. Thanks

Comment: You might ask this on FMETalk if you haven't already. Also if French is your first language I bet some of the Safe support people speak it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An FME workspace can handle any amount of data in any format if it is predefined in the workspace. If it cannot be predefined then FME has special functionality to read any format of data (what we call "Generic") and read any data schema ("Dynamic").

In this case it's unlikely that the Generic functionality will help. Firstly there is no need for it because the format will always be the same and secondly (as pointed out) the Generic reader won't work with database formats (it's a file only technology).

Whether you will need to use the dynamic functionality depends on the nature of the other Geodatabases.

If all Geodatabases will contain the same set of tables/classes, then you don't need to use the Dynamic tools. You just need to pick a different Geodatabase at run time and it will run to completion.

If the Geodatabases will contain different tables/classes, or the same tables with different attributes, then you need to use Dynamic functionality.

Do it like this:

1) When creating the workspace, check the Dynamic Option on the dialog:

[image: Dynamic Option]

2) This will create a workspace like this, with one layer only and no attributes:

[image: Dynamic Workspace]

3) Run this workspace (File > Prompt and Run) and you get prompted to select which tables (Feature Types) to read. You can choose any of them:

[image: Feature Types to Read]

4) This gives you the required output:

[image: Output]

5) The next time you run the translation you can choose a different Geodatabase. This gives a different set of tables to read:

[image: Different Geodatabase]

6) But because the workspace is dynamic, it works just the same:

[image: Different Output]

This is obviously being run from within Workbench. But run from Server the effect will be the same.

Hope this helps. Sorry for such a lengthy post!

Comment: This is exactly what I was getting towards; you are better and getting through your docs than I was.

Comment: It's dynamic operation with FME Server. So How to read the feature type dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something similar to this from [FMEpedia Sample download](http://fmeserver.com/userweb/sharper/Portal/EasyTranslator/index.html) that is available from Safe. The sample download and setup is pretty easy, I use a stripped down version in a process to convert files on the fly into a staging location.
 blah238 is right, you can post to [FMETalk](http://groups.google.com/group/fmetalk) or browse through [FMEPedia](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Main_Page) and get a lot of info. Plus is atleast one SAFE person who pops through here quite often (*Hey Mark are you listening?*) that can give you some scoop as well.
 
**Better Answer I think...**
 Ok, I think what you really may be looking for is the [Generic](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Generic_Format) format reader. This is the magic in the sample I reference above; this will let you define a array of the formats to read-in and write out that will get you to what I think you are really looking for. So you couple this with the DynamicSchema and you can import just about anything and then run it through your other steps to output what you need.

Comment: Generic reader won't work with databases, which I'm not positive but I would imagine includes ESRI file geodatabases.

Comment: Correct GENERIC READER will not work with database formats only single file formats

Comment: Sorry for my language ! > blah238.

Comment: I suspect Generic Reader will work with Personal Geodatabases (since they are a single file) but not with File Geodatabases (which aren't a single file - go figure!) Whether it will be able to tell - automatically - the difference between a Geodatabase MDB file, a GeoMedia MDB file, or a plain Access MDB file I'm not sure!

Comment: Generic Reader work fine with Geodatabases Files (FME Desktop 2012 sp5)